# How can I perform functions on a specified subset of rows?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, gnumeric

I want to find the max (min, average, etc.) of a column but only for the subset of rows where another column matches a certain pattern.

For example, here is the data in the sheet named "data":

```
Date   Value
Jan    15
Jan    17
Jan    3
Feb    19
Feb    34
Feb    37
```

Then in a separate sheet, "reports", I'd like to have:

```
       Jan    Feb
Max    17     37
Min    3      19
```

What function I can put in the cells in the "reports" sheet to get those values?

If it matters, I'm using Gnumeric 1.10.

Comment: It'd be better if you put some of your attempts in your question...

Comment: Are you looking for a cell function or code? For the former, you would use `MAX()` and `MIN()` along with some other functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve:

```
=max(column b where column a == Jan)
```

You can use an `IF` to do that:

```
=MAX(IF(A2:A7="Jan", B2:B7))
```

This formula should be entered as an array formula however. In excel, you do this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: @drewbenn Putting the formula in a different cell shouldn't affect the outcome, unless the references are changing as well, in which case, you're not putting the correct formula... Changing A4 to `Mar` shouldn't change anything either. `A4` has `Feb` and doesn't affect any `Jan`. [spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Am9GG-rwdOL1dFRpVGV2dWl5dEcxY1NzTVlWM2l0a0E&usp=sharing)